# Google Calendar redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, port, google-calendar-api

I have a website in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web.

I keep getting an error from google which says there isn't a match for the redirect uri's listed in the developer console when I try the code below:

```
private void getEvents()
    {
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               new ClientSecrets
               {
                   ClientId = "CLIENTIDHERE",
                   ClientSecret = "SECRETHERE",
               },
               new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
               "user",
               CancellationToken.None).Result;

        // Create the service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });

        List<Event> x = service.Events.List("primary").Execute().Items.ToList();
    }
```

I have already tried setting the default port to 8080 in visual studio and the URI's listed in my developer console are as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/QFC/Coach/Manageusers.aspx

http://localhost:8080/QFC/*

http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback

http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback/

http://localhost:8080/authorize

http://localhost:8080/authorize/

http://localhost:8080/signin-google
```

The code mentioned above is called from `http://localhost:8080/QFC/Coach/Schedule.aspx` on page load.
Each time I get the error the port number is different and I have no idea why. 
e.g. `http://localhost:57002/authorize/` did not match a registered

**I am using the .NET api with C#**

**I need to know why it's doing this and how to fix it.**

Comment: When you run Visual studio in debug mode the port changes.  You need to figure out how to set it up to not change port.

Comment: I noticed that too now... I fixed it by adding: http://localhost/authorize/ to the list of uris. Thanks!

Comment: Do not forget to accept your own answer (when time allows it) then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added `http://localhost/authorize/` to the list of allowed URI's. This somehow makes google verification ignore the port. But it works!

Comment: I'm having the same problem and tried to add so many different URIs, also http(s)://localhost/authorize. The problem is that the port always changes and Google doesn't ignore it! Did you also configure the OAuth2 authentication service for Google in your Project?

Comment: No I didn't... I struggled for a long time with this, and adding that line to the list of allowed URI's just fixed it. I did nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was doing the quickstart with no prior knowledge of Google Calendar API. The solution was adding:

```
http://localhost/
```

and waiting a few minutes for an update